# Micro SD card compatible with Pi 3 Model B

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, kodi, htpc

I bought a new Pi 3 Model B to use as a Kodi media centre.  I based my Micro SD card choice on this tutorial:

http://mymediaexperience.com/raspberry-pi-xbmc-with-raspbmc/

...and I bought the SD card recommended in the tutorial:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008RJU4R0/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&creativeASIN=B008RJU4R0&linkCode=as2&tag=diglivroo-20&linkId=FAZETLSC5G3GW573](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008RJU4R0)

However, I cannot boot my Pi and now think this card might not be supported?  Can anyone confirm and recommend me a good SD card which is definitely compatible?

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is that your card is not supported? What happens instead of booting? What do you actually see on your screen?

Comment: Hi. Have you checked the list on elinux? The have an ever updated and comprehensive list of working sd cards http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards

Comment: I assume it is the SD card because when I boot, I get the red LED on light but no output to the monitor.  I have changed HDMI cables and re-seated the card but wtill no luck.

Comment: My card is not appearing on the elinux list but a close fit is: Extreme Pro (95MB/s UHS-I) (SDSDQXP-016G-AFFP)   which shows as not working.  I am just confused as that tutorial specifically links to the card I bought.

Comment: Most of the posts about SD Cards are rubbish. There are some bad cards out there, but any card from a reputable manufacturer will be OK. There is absolutely no point in buying fancy cards, as the Pi doesn't support them. Anything beyond Class 10 is a waste, and you will be hard pressed to tell any difference from a Class 4. Manufactureres DO NOT rate cards on the most important characteristic for a Pi viz. frequent small writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SD card you have bought is indeed compatible. Unless your card is defective or physically damaged (which you would have discovered when flashing it), it is not the source of your problem.

You may want to run a flash testing tool of your choice to be sure. Something like `FakeFlashTest` or `H2testw` would do.

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware what 'flashing' is. I have put the SD card in and powered the Pi up.  I was expecting to see some kind of first time boot screen which would allow me to connect to internet and download an OS?

Comment: @Steerpike you can't boot the Pi without even installing an operating system on the SD Card

Comment: @MohamedBelal ok, back to basics then!  How do I get an OS on the card?

Comment: @Steerpike Now there's your problem, you simply have no software on your card. Considering your tutorial, you probably want either [OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/get-openelec/category/7-raspberry-pi2-builds) or [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/download/). Those download pages have links to installation instructions.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - yes, thank you - what I need to know is: how do I get an OS on the card!!

Comment: @Steerpike you can check official raspberry pi guide here https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

Comment: @Steerpike Gosh you're impatient! Read the tutorial you have found in full. Or check the download pages I've linked to: they also have instructions.

Comment: first download raspbian os from here https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ then check the "WRITING AN IMAGE TO THE SD CARD" section here https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

Comment: @MohamedBelal I think Steerpike wants an image with KodiTV, not plain Jessie desktop.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev oh sorry i forgot that part then he got to follow your instructions for OSMC or OpenELEC

Comment: OK - the information I have been missing is that I need an SD card reader to be able to insert the SD card into my PC to download the image.

Comment: @Steerpike yep, you do. And if you get an **SD** card reader, you'll also need an adapter to plug a **microSD** card in it (the card you bought is a microSD). The adapter possibly came with the card. Or, you can buy a microSD reader like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Voberry%C2%AE-5Gbps-Super-Reader-Adapter/dp/B012D3A4FM/ref=pd_lpo_147_tr_t_3?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=PZH8DKJ9XK0JTBSC45GY).

Comment: @Steerpike Good luck! Note that if you encounter more issues, you should create new questions rather than posting here. Also, you can "accept" the answer once your issue is solved.